# wxWidgets AddRoot() on wxTreeCtrl fails to add more then one node

Tags: c++, treeview, wxwidgets

I'm using wxWidgets 2.8.11 on Windows 7 64 Bit. I created a wxTreeCtrl control, which as the name suggests, is a tree control. You can add Root nodes by calling AddRoot(), however it seems to only work the first time of calling it.

Here is the code where I create the Tree:

```
newHandler-> sendPacketTree = new wxTreeCtrl(newHandler->sendGroupBox,4,wxPoint(7,12),wxSize(newHandler->sendGroupBox->GetSize().x-14,newHandler->sendGroupBox->GetSize().y-20),wxTR_DEFAULT_STYLE);
```

Here is what I'm doing just as a test:

```
this->sendPacketTree->AddRoot(wxT("Test1"));
this->sendPacketTree->AddRoot(wxT("Test2"));
```

However, only the first root node appears in the Tree, and the second node doesn't appear (or any other node after the first node for that matter)

Does anyone know why this is happening, or how I can get around this? I'm stumped.

Comment: To see more code than the two lines that are failing would help.

Comment: Alright, I added the snippet where the tree is created... I couldn't think of anything else that is relevant.

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution on my own. I thought that AddRoot() allowed you to add more then one root. It turns out you can only have one root, but you are able to hide the actual "root", and any children of the root will look like a root with the `wxTR_HIDE_ROOT` style set.